# How to separate filename from path? basename() versus preg_split() with array_pop()

Tags: php, regex, filenames, filepath

Why use `basename()` in PHP scripts if what this function is actually doing may be written in 2 lines:

```
$subFolders = preg_split("!\\\|\\/!ui", $path);  // explode on `\` or `/`
$name = array_pop($subFolder);  // extract last element's value (filename)
```

Am I missing something?

However I guess this code above may not work correctly **if** file name has some `\` or `/` in it. But that's not possible, right?

Comment: How about you are missing that not everyone is as comfortable with regex as you are?

Comment: PS where did $subf come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP may run on many different systems with many different filesystems and naming conventions. Using a function like `basename()` guarantees (or at least, is supposed to guarantee) a correct result regardless of the platform. This increases the code's portability.

Also, compare a simple `basename()` call to your code - which is more readable, and more obvious to other programmers in regards to what it is supposed to do?