# PHP Remove part of a string

Tags: php, string

How can I remove all the slashes from the following string? All I want is the image name.

The string is:

```
listingimages//uPLhHJtvIZ//architecture-1836070__340.jpg
```

And all I want is the

```
architecture-1836070__340.jpg
```

I still get confused about preg_match and replace.

Comment: Show us your preg_match attempt

Comment: how about basename? http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to separate filename from path? basename() versus preg\_split() with array\_pop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859628/how-to-separate-filename-from-path-basename-versus-preg-split-with-array-po)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try BaseName (http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
echo basename("listingimages//uPLhHJtvIZ//architecture-1836070__340.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally assuming you want to grab the file name [basename()](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvhbqqnffVAhWHtI8KHUJCA5cQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.basename.php&usg=AFQjCNFjSVdDIYDxs8gMNT12I_fSyQYhBg) should help but still just a suggestion with explode :D

A simple and quick solution with explode :

```
$image_path ="listingimages//uPLhHJtvIZ//architecture-1836070__340.jpg";  
$image_name = explode("//",$image_path);

echo $image_name [count($image_name )-1];
```